# Can Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 for students be used to publish commercial products?

Tags: software

I was a student at a university and i was provided free Microsoft applications through Microsoft Imagine. I have graduated but i still have those applications especially Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. I would like to know am i permitted to use this application and can i publish the applications developed using this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot as it violates the terms of the student licence for Microsoft Visual Studio.

You can, however, use the Community version of Visual Studio to publish those apps - it lacks some of the features of the Enterprise version, most notably the team integration features but if you are doing this one off that shouldn't bother you.